# Change of inequalities in logs?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logarithms, exponential-function

hope everyone is doing well and safe. I was wondering how the inequalities change (second to third line)? Also, is the third derived from the second line by change of base theorem? I've tried out a few methods but i'm unable to get an answer. Thank you in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It goes so:

Since $\log_{10}$ increases, we obtain:
$$\log_{10}0.8^n<\log_{10}0.1$$ or
$$n\log_{10}0.8<\log_{10}0.1$$ or
$$n>\frac{\log_{10}0.1}{\log_{10}0.8}$$ because $\log_{10}0.8<0.$

Comment: Could you explain why $\log_{10}0.8<0.$ would turn the inequality around? Because I made a similar assumption but ended up with $$-n<\frac{\log_{10}0.1}{\log_{10}0.8}$$. I'm honestly not too sure why i'm so confused right now haha.

Comment: @Munchies  Your last should be $-n<-\frac{\log_{10}0.1}{\log_{10}0.8}$. Also. For example: If $a<0$ so $b<c\Leftrightarrow ab>ac$ because $ab-bc=a(b-c)>0.$

Comment: Ohhhh righttt!!!!! Thanks so much for the help!! Really appreciate the explanation